# ExcelJS writeFile not working: Uncaught TypeError: fs.createWriteStream is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, xlsx, exceljs

I'm trying to export a formatted excel file using ExcelJS and the writeFile method simply isn't working. I get the following exception when I call the function:

`Uncaught TypeError: fs.createWriteStream is not a function`

My javascript is bundled using browserify.js. Here's my source code:

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <title>Test Excel JS</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="description" content="">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div>
    <label>Test</label>
    <button onclick="test()">Test this Stuff and Check your console log</button>
  </div>

  <script src="bundle.js"></script>
  <script>
      var test = function(){
          writeFile();
      };
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

app.js (bundled by browserify into bundle.js)

```
'use strict';

global.Excel = require('../node_modules/exceljs/dist/es5/exceljs.browser');

global.isRowBold = function(excelRow){
    return excelRow.getCell('name').value === "Jeff";
};

global.getRowColor = function(excelRow){
    return excelRow.getCell('color').value;
};

global.getCellColor = function(excelRow, cell){
    return (excelRow.getCell('name').value === 'John' && cell.value === 0)? 'orange' : excelRow.getCell('color').value;
};

global.getFont = function(isBold, color){
    return {
        name: 'Arial Black',
        color: color,
        family: 2,
        size: 14,
        bold: isBold
    };
};

global.getTestHeader = function(){
    return [
        {key: "id", header: "Id"},
        {key: "name", header: "Name", width: 32},
        {key: "color", header: "Color", width: 10}
    ];
};

global.getTestData = function(){
    return [
        {
            id: 0,
            name: "John",
            color: "green"
        },
        {
            id: 1,
            name: "Rehan",
            color: "blue"
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            name: "Jeff",
            color: "yellow"
        }
    ];
};

global.generateTestFile = function(){
    var workbook = new Excel.Workbook();

    workbook.creator = "Generated";
    workbook.lastModifiedBy = "Generated";
    workbook.created = new Date();
    workbook.modified = new Date();

    var worksheet = workbook.addWorksheet('Sheet 1');

    //Set Column Headers
    worksheet.columns = getTestHeader();

    //Add Rows
    var testData = getTestData();
    var length = testData.length;
    for(var i = 0; i < length; i++){
        worksheet.addRow(testData[i]);
    }

    //Format Rows
    worksheet.eachRow(function(row, rowNumber){
        var isBold = isRowBold(row);
        row.eachCell(function(cell, colNumber){
            var cellColor = getCellColor(row, cell);
            cell.font = getFont(isBold, cellColor);
        });
    });

    //workbook.commit();
    return workbook;
};

global.writeFile = function(){
    var workbook = generateTestFile();
    workbook.xlsx.writeFile('./output/newtestfile.xlsx')
        .then(function() {
            console.log('Done Writing file');
        });
};
```

Comment: You can't browserify modules that depend on server-side features (like reading from or writing to the filesystem).

Answer (score 6):

change writeFile to writeBuffer

**use filesaver**

```
workbook.xlsx.writeBuffer()
  .then(buffer => FileSaver.saveAs(new Blob([buffer]), `${Date.now()}_feedback.xlsx`))
  .catch(err => console.log('Error writing excel export', err)
```

Comment: There is an ")" left at the end

Answer (score 3):

`fs.createWriteStream` is a method meant to be used on Node.js (server). These kinds of methods won't be available on the browser (client-side).